# Animating img scale cause shaking effect during transition

Tags: css, flexbox, css-animations, css-transitions, scale

Edited

I'm using css transitions to increase scale of an img while hovering it.
I don't know why on my website during the transition the img seems shaking (especially at start and ending of the transition). I tried to removed the blur effect but this dont fix the issue.
I tried to replicate it on code pen and there it works fine.

In this video you can see on code pen how the transition is so fluid:

[Ok video](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/q3wcxxxpuycabydsdlfe9/ok.mov?rlkey=dff2vdlxiulzgudrzgxds7e8q&dl=0)

Here ow on my website isn't so fluid and shake e littel bit:

[Shake video](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/a9xairy4evvg0aziq5aoi/shake.mov?rlkey=97irwwljgizk5vrl0dbkaln6t&dl=0)

My code pen code:

```
<div id="focus_last_proj" class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_3 et_pb_with_background et_section_regular">
    <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_3">
            <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_6  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_filterable_portfolio et_pb_filterable_portfolio_0 et_pb_portfolio  et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_filterable_portfolio_grid clearfix" data-posts-number="10" style="display: block;">
          
                <div class="et_pb_portfolio_filters clearfix"><ul class="clearfix"><li class="et_pb_portfolio_filter et_pb_portfolio_filter_all"><a href="#" class="active" data-category-slug="all">Tutto</a></li><li class="et_pb_portfolio_filter"><a href="#" data-category-slug="ultimi_progetti">ultimi progetti</a></li></ul></div>

                <div class="et_pb_portfolio_items_wrapper clearfix">
                    <div class="et_pb_portfolio_items">             <div id="post-658" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_disegno_industriale project_category_ultimi_progetti et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_0 post-658 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-disegno_industriale project_category-ultimi_progetti active first_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/lancia-delta/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" fetchpriority="high" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/deltone-prw-rect.jpg" alt="Lancia Delta" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/deltone-prw-rect.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/deltone-prw-rect-980x490.jpg 980w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/deltone-prw-rect-480x240.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 980px) 980px, (min-width: 981px) 9999px, 100vw">                                <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/lancia-delta/">Lancia Delta</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/disegno_industriale/" rel="tag">product</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a></p>                </div>
                                <div id="post-655" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_grafica project_category_ultimi_progetti et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_1 post-655 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-grafica project_category-ultimi_progetti active last_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/lo-sciatore/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/lo-sciatore-prw-square.jpg" alt="Lo Sciatore" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/lo-sciatore-prw-square.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/lo-sciatore-prw-square-480x480.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) 9999px, 100vw">                             <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/lo-sciatore/">Lo Sciatore</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/grafica/" rel="tag">graphic</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a></p>              </div>
                                <div id="post-653" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_ultimi_progetti project_category_siti_web et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_2 post-653 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-ultimi_progetti project_category-siti_web active first_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/la-terrazza/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/la-terrazza-prw-vert.jpg" alt="La Terrazza" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/la-terrazza-prw-vert.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/la-terrazza-prw-vert-480x720.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) 9999px, 100vw">                               <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/la-terrazza/">La Terrazza</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/siti_web/" rel="tag">web</a></p>             </div>
                                <div id="post-651" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_ultimi_progetti project_category_siti_web et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_3 post-651 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-ultimi_progetti project_category-siti_web active last_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/fb-aurum/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/fb-aurum-prw-vert.jpg" alt="FB-Aurum" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/fb-aurum-prw-vert.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/fb-aurum-prw-vert-480x720.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) 9999px, 100vw">                               <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/fb-aurum/">FB-Aurum</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/siti_web/" rel="tag">web</a></p>               </div>
                                <div id="post-649" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_grafica project_category_ultimi_progetti et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_4 post-649 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-grafica project_category-ultimi_progetti active first_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/t-shirt-point-du-sport/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pds-tshirt-prw-vert.jpg" alt="T-shirt Point du Sport" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pds-tshirt-prw-vert.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pds-tshirt-prw-vert-480x720.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) 9999px, 100vw">                               <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/t-shirt-point-du-sport/">T-shirt Point du Sport</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/grafica/" rel="tag">graphic</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a></p>                </div>
                                <div id="post-643" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_grafica project_category_ultimi_progetti et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_5 post-643 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-grafica project_category-ultimi_progetti active last_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/les-pommes-du-mont-blanc/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/lpdmb-prw-square.jpg" alt="Les Pommes du Mont Blanc" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/lpdmb-prw-square.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/lpdmb-prw-square-480x480.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) 9999px, 100vw">                               <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/les-pommes-du-mont-blanc/">Les Pommes du Mont Blanc</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/grafica/" rel="tag">graphic</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a></p>                </div>
                                <div id="post-588" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_grafica project_category_ultimi_progetti et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_6 post-588 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-grafica project_category-ultimi_progetti active first_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/petigax/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/ptgx-prw-square.jpg" alt="Petigax" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/ptgx-prw-square.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/ptgx-prw-square-480x480.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) 9999px, 100vw">                               <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/petigax/">Petigax</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/grafica/" rel="tag">graphic</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a></p>              </div>
                                <div id="post-585" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_grafica project_category_ultimi_progetti et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_7 post-585 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-grafica project_category-ultimi_progetti active last_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/la-grange/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/la-grange-prw-vert.jpg" alt="La Grange" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/la-grange-prw-vert.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/la-grange-prw-vert-480x720.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) 9999px, 100vw">                                <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/la-grange/">La Grange</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/grafica/" rel="tag">graphic</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a></p>              </div>
                                <div id="post-582" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_disegno_industriale project_category_ultimi_progetti et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_8 post-582 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-disegno_industriale project_category-ultimi_progetti project_tag-span2 active first_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/render-3d-metro-roma/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/metro-roma-rect.jpg" alt="Render 3d metro Roma" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/metro-roma-rect.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/metro-roma-rect-980x490.jpg 980w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/metro-roma-rect-480x240.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 980px) 980px, (min-width: 981px) 9999px, 100vw">                              <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/render-3d-metro-roma/">Render 3d metro Roma</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/disegno_industriale/" rel="tag">product</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a></p>                </div>
                                <div id="post-579" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_grafica project_category_disegno_industriale project_category_ultimi_progetti et_pb_filterable_portfolio_item_0_9 post-579 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-grafica project_category-disegno_industriale project_category-ultimi_progetti active last_in_row" style="display: block;">
                                        <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/micro-birrificio-courmayeur-monte-bianco/">
                            <span class="et_portfolio_image">
                                <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/mbc-prw-square.jpg" alt="Micro Birrificio Courmayeur Monte Bianco" class="" width="9999" height="9999" srcset="https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/mbc-prw-square.jpg 9999w, https://www.jcprod.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/mbc-prw-square-480x480.jpg 480w" sizes="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) 480px, (min-width: 481px) 9999px, 100vw">                             <span class="et_overlay"></span>                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <h2 class="et_pb_module_header"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project/micro-birrificio-courmayeur-monte-bianco/">Micro Birrificio Courmayeur Monte Bianco</a></h2><p class="post-meta"><a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/grafica/" rel="tag">graphic</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/disegno_industriale/" rel="tag">product</a>, <a href="https://www.jcprod.it/project_category/ultimi_progetti/" rel="tag">ultimi progetti</a></p>               </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="et_pb_portofolio_pagination"><ul></ul></div>
            </div>
    </div>
                
                
                
                
    </div>
                
                
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{background:black;}
.et_pb_row{ width:90vw;margin:auto;}
#focus_last_proj .et_pb_portfolio_items{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
/*column-gap: 20px;
grid-auto-rows: 12.5vw;*/
  grid-gap:20px;
  
  grid-template-areas:
    'h h h h i i l l'
    'h h h h i i l l'
    'd d e e i i g g'
    'd d e e f f g g'
    'd d b b f f g g'
    'a a b b c c c c'
    'a a b b c c c c';
}
#post-588{grid-area:a;}
#post-585{grid-area:b;}
#post-582{grid-area:c;}
#post-651{grid-area:d;}
#post-579{grid-area:e;}
#post-643{grid-area:f;}
#post-649{grid-area:g;}
#post-658{grid-area:h;}
#post-653{grid-area:i;}
#post-655{grid-area:l;}

.et_pb_portfolio_item{position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.et_pb_portfolio_item img{width:100%;height:100%;object-fit:cover;transition:transform 1s;}

#focus_last_proj .et_pb_portfolio_item h2,#focus_last_proj .et_pb_portfolio_item p{position:absolute;top:0;}

.et_pb_portfolio_item:hover img{transform:scale(105%);transition:transform 1s;}
```

[My website](https://www.jcprod.it/)

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/jean-chiementin/pen/MWZKZed)

Comment: It's a bit difficult to debug something that works! Can you extract just enough code from your website to make a runnable snippet which shows the problem. Try to remove extraneous code - perhaps just show the phenomenon on one image only. And please check the snippet really does show the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You right, if on codepen it works fine I think the problem is linked to some default Divi page builder's style rules, but can't find which ones